# Create a smooth curving object with constant wall thickness using Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing

Create a smooth curving object with constant wall thickness using Geometry nodes.

I'm trying to recreate a funnel (`Left image`) using geometry nodes to make it parametric (`Right image`)

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

I'm running into two issues:

**1st issue** the top wall thickness changes due to the `Scale Elements node` (see arrows).  **How can I make it so the wall thickness remains constant with geometry nodes?**

**2nd issue** the sharp angles are created when using the `Extrude node` (see arrows)  **How can I make it so it curves up smoothly using geometry nodes.**

**See attached Blend file.**

[image]

**PS:  This will be 3D printed so a constant wall thickness is useful.**

Comment: concerning the aspect you mentioned this can be done, but... for the top profile, compared to the original, the concave part are less scaled than the convex ones. And that is not really possible to acheive, I think. Except maybe if the inputs are the bottom profile and the top one.

Comment: an image that shows what I mean (original is on the right): https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XtyE.png

Comment: @lemon that image looks like the wall thickness is maintained if not very close to doing so.

Comment: yes the thickness is maintained, but the shape (on top) is just scaled. That's why it looks different from the model.